# How to make a single image in to different(optimize) sizes once image uploaded?

Tags: image, image-processing, asp.net-mvc-4

here i had taken
this as i am sending to u just look at once please chek it once is this is the right way to do this work

```
 UploadController  class file


 public class UploadController : ApiController
    {


    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var uploadFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/app_data");
        uploadFolder = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff"));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);
        var streamProvider = new PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider(uploadFolder);

        var parts = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
        foreach (var uploadedFile in Directory.GetFiles(uploadFolder))
        {
            var thumbnail = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "thumb-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
            var medium = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "medium-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
            var large = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "large-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
            ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, thumbnail, 100, 100);
            ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, medium, 200, 200);
            ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, large, 300, 300);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
```

and i had taken a separate file for imagetools in models folder

```
 public class imageTools
    {
        public static void Resize(string original, string output, int width, int height)
        {
            using (var image = Image.FromFile(original))
            using (var thumbnail = new Bitmap(width, height))
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail))
            {
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

                graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

                ImageCodecInfo[] info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
                EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
                encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
                thumbnail.Save(output, info[1], encoderParameters);
            }
        }
    }
```

and i had taken one more file with the name

```
  PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider




    public class PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider : MultipartFileStreamProvider
    {
        public PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider(string rootPath)
            : base(rootPath)
        {
        }

        public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
        {
            return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
```

and finally my layout page

```
     @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "images" }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="image" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [ImageResizer package](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfWeek11ImageResizerEnablesCleanClearImageResizingInASPNET.aspx). Or you could also [implement image resizing yourself](http://keyvan.io/very-high-quality-image-resizing-in-net).

---

UPDATE: Here's an example that you could use to resize the uploaded images in a Web API controller.

You could start by writing a Resize method that will use GDI+ as shown in the previous article that I have linked to:

```
public static class ImageTools
{
    public static void Resize(string original, string output, int width, int height)
    {
        using (var image = Image.FromFile(original))
        using (var thumbnail = new Bitmap(width, height))
        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnail))
        {
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

            graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

            ImageCodecInfo[] info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
            encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
            thumbnail.Save(output, info[1], encoderParameters);
        }
    }
}
```

and then a custom `MultipartFileStreamProvider` that will preserve the originally uploaded filename:

```
public class PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider : MultipartFileStreamProvider
{
    public PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider(string rootPath): base(rootPath)
    {
    }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        return headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
    }
}
```

and finally you could have an API controller that will receive the uploaded images, store them in the `App_Data` folder and generated different formats by resizing them:

```
public class ImagesController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var uploadFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/app_data");
        uploadFolder = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff"));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);
        var streamProvider = new PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider(uploadFolder);

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
        foreach (var uploadedFile in Directory.GetFiles(uploadFolder))
        {
            var thumbnail = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "thumb-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
            var medium = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "medium-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
            var large = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "large-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
            ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, thumbnail, 100, 100);
            ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, medium, 200, 200);
            ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, large, 300, 300);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
}
```

finally you could have an HTML form that will allow the user to upload images:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "images" }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="file" name="image" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    }
</body>  
</html>
```

---

UPDATE 2:

It seems that you are using .NET 4.0. Here's a revised version of the `ImagesController` that will work with .NET 4.0:

```
public class ImagesController : ApiController
{
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var uploadFolder = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/app_data");
        uploadFolder = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssfff"));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);
        var streamProvider = new PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider(uploadFolder);

        return Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            foreach (var uploadedFile in Directory.GetFiles(uploadFolder))
            {
                var thumbnail = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "thumb-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
                var medium = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "medium-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
                var large = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, "large-" + Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile));
                ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, thumbnail, 100, 100);
                ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, medium, 200, 200);
                ImageTools.Resize(uploadedFile, large, 300, 300);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it is better but i need to do this by manully like writing hard code how can i do this is there any idea please help

Comment: Did you read the article I have linked to in my answer (the second one about manually resizing an image using GDI+)? What have you tried? What difficulties did you encounter?

Comment: yes it's working in mvc3(webapi) right but i need to do this work manually in mvc4 thank you for your reply if any help please help me

Comment: What have you tried? Could you show your code? What problems did you encounter? I have updated my answer to illustrate an example that could get you started.

Comment: thank you for your reply let me try this example that you are updated

Comment: thank you for reply but i am getting error                                                  var streamProvider = new PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider(uploadFolder); at this line

Comment: Did you define the `PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider` class as shown in my answer? it's a custom class that you need to write.

Comment: yes i define it PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider is it should i(define) write in the same controller file

Comment: What error are you getting? What's the error message? Also please define this in a separate file. Don't mix it with your controller.

Comment: it showing the same error PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider even i had define in separate class file likr in models (class,file)and i had called models namspace

Comment: What's the error message? `PreserveFilenameMultipartFileStreamProvider` is not an error - it's the name of a custom class that you need to write as shown in my answer.

Comment: "Expected class ,dekegete,enum,interface or struct" it is showing this error

Comment: You must have done something wrong and not as I showed in my answer. Could you please post your full source code? And this is basic C#. You should be familiar with the language before getting into ASP.NET MVC. You most definitely have some typo error. Please learn the language before getting into more complex things or you will never be able to understand anything.

Comment: k i will post the code thank you for spending time for me i wil tell you what i had done here k first i had taken a Uploadcontroller calls

Comment: mr. Darin Dimitrov thank you for spending time for me please look i had edited my file here

Comment: Your `imageTools` class starts with lowercase `i`. And yet when you are calling it you are calling it with uppercase `I`. C# is a case sensitive language.

Comment: please check it even i had called the namespace of models folders in controllers

Comment: `public class imageTools` should be `public class ImageTools`. Also make sure that you have included all namespaces. I can't believe that you cannot make this work. That's really basic C#. Please stop working on ASP.NET MVC and read some getting started tutorial about C# as you seem to be struggling a lot with things like classes and namespaces.

Comment: k you had written async is this is variable or i should call any namespace for it

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.5? async/await are concepts that were introduced in .NET 4.5. They will not work in .NET 4.0. Which version are you using? For this to work you need VS2012 and be targetting .NET 4.5.

Comment: OK, I will update my answer for .NET 4.0. And next time you ask a question please make sure to provide those kind of details because they are very important. See now my `UPDATE 2` at the end.

Comment: thats really an nice answer given by @DarinDimitrov ...very breif in concept ,in fact i was looking for some thing like this...u made my day

Comment: Thankyou mr.Darin Dimitrov its working you are super friend thankyou so mach for spent time for me thank you friend

Comment: @DarinDimitrov hi..in you case the file size is increasing after the files have been uploaded how do i restrict the file size to..